# When to start separate process in android ?

Tags: android, android-service, android-intentservice

I have 100 of images to download from server and each one size is nearly 200kb.To serve this purpose in the app,I may have to go for creating Service OR Intent service. I know that intent service is best fit in this situation because it runs on worker thread. but my only concern is, my application will also initiate other threads for different needs. so too many thread at time may leads to performance degradations. so i am in dilemma of making decision for intent service or service in separate process altogether. creating separate process might be benefitted in all the way. what do you say ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. If you remember your first multi-threading class you might be told that all threads don't work simultaneously but it is like "one runs for a while then second runs then one runs again then maybe third and so on" order is random. It doesn't affect performance because for the processor it doesn't matter if you use 2 threads or 100. 
However make sure you don't wait for ,  say first 10, images to download first so that user don't have to wait too long for images to download o a slow connection.

Answer (score 0):

Of course that Intent Service running in worker thread and Service running in Main Thread. So if you want to download images in Service you still need create new Thread so it's same work here, but Intent Service have some advantages over Service :

```
1.Background thread ( You no need to create Thread to download images when Service need)

2.Automatic queuing the Intents delivered to onStartCommand(), so if one Intent is being processed by onHandleIntent() on the background thread, other commands queue up waiting their turn.

3. the automatic shutdown of the IntentService when job done (in service you need to call stopService)
```

About create new Process it's no need. Just create one IntentService to download your images. With bigger data you can make multiple thread and download multiple part at same time but 100 images and 200kb each is really no need it.